# What program should I use to make a gzipped xml (xml.gz) file?

Tags: xml, gzip

I really need help with finding a program which will allow me to edit `xml.gz` files. To be honest I'm not even sure what a `xml.gz` file is for that matter. If it's a compressed xml file then I would also like to ask how to compress a xml file. So to sum it up I'd like to know some program suggestions and an explanation about `xml.gz` files.

Comment: How is this programming related?

Comment: XML file is just a compressed XML file

Answer (score 10):

It's just a compressed .xml file. e.g. to create

```
gzip file.xml
```

which creates the file with the suffix `.gz`.

And to decompress

```
gunzip file.xml.gz
```

(The gzip utilities will likely be standard on your Unix, or they're available via [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) for Windows).

Note that some editors will let you edit the `.gz` file by uncompressing it on the fly for you, so you don't need to uncompress *then* edit (e.g. [vim](http://www.vim.org))

Comment: and to uncompress to stdout, zcat file.xml.gz

Answer (score 4):

### Create the XML file with any tool.

after that, if on Unix/Linux - you may use [**gzip**](http://www.gzip.org/):

**To compress**

```
$gzip <path>/filename.xml
```

You will have the compressed `filename.xml.gz` in the same folder.

**To decompress**

```
$gzip -d <path>/filename.xml.gz
```

In case of windows, you may use ***7zip***

Answer (score 1):

(to nudge the thread programming-wards)

To read/write gzip files programatically, one could try the zlib library which enables read/write to gzip files using a similar interfaces to fopen/fwrite/fclose.

http://www.zlib.net/manual.html#gzopen

In python, it's a lot simpler -- using the gzip module:
http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/gzip/

Answer (score 0):

From the entry in [Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip):

> gzip is a software application used for file compression. gzip is short for GNU zip.

You can unzip the file with a proper tool depending on your operating system, edit your document, then compress it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can find executables at http://www.gzip.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can uncompress an xml.gz file on a standard Linux distribution with the command

```
gunzip file.xml.gz
```

And likewise compress it with the command

```
gzip file.xml
```

On windows you can use your favorite archive manager or use [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) if you don't have one.